# Mod causing artifacts in ParametricPlot3D

Tags: graphics3d, parametric-functions

I used `NDSolve` and `ParametricPlot3D` to plot geodesics on a misshapen "torus", like so:
[image]

I wanted to treat it as a surface of revolution, and then simply use `Mod[x[t],2Pi]` to have each geodesic loop back onto this single portion of the surface. However, as you can see, there are some strange artifacts on graph when I use `Mod`. If I treat the surface like normal, then there are no artifacts, so I know it's not part of the calculation.

How should I go about getting these to disappear? Ideally, I'd like to plot geodesics for large times, and watch the path. However every time the path leaves one end, it produces one of these artifacts, which clutters up the picture considerably.

Comment: Could you give an example of the code you use to produce this image? My guess is that the path you make when you use `Mod`will just simply join the start and end points with a straight line, hence giving rise to the artefacts. Most likely you will need to plot each segment separately.

Comment: Looks like a job for `Exclusions -> Sin[2t] == 0`.

Comment: Here is the code for the path (sorry, I accidentally posted the line of code for the surface before):
`ParametricPlot3D[
 Evaluate[{Mod[xx[x[t], \[Theta][t]], 2 \[Pi]], yy[x[t], \[Theta][t]],
     zz[x[t], \[Theta][t]]} /. soln], {t, 0, 100}]`
I just added `Exclusions -> {Sin[2 t] == 0}` to the `ParametricPlot3d`, but it didn't do anything.

Comment: `xx[x[t], \[Theta][t]]`, etc are the x, y, and z component functions. Each depends on the x and theta parameters, which were solved for by NDSolve.

Comment: @Patch I would try to see if you get the same behaviour with systems where you know the geodesics and you have analytical equations such as:  `Show[RevolutionPlot3D[{2 + Sin[t], t}, {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
  PlotStyle -> White], 
 ParametricPlot3D[{2 + Sin[t], 0, Mod[t, 2 \[Pi]]}, {t, 0, 4 \[Pi]}, 
  PlotStyle -> Red]]` For this example I don't get the straight lines? Is this similar enough to what you did based on your numerical solution?

Comment: @Dunlop On a related note: I tried using a `Manipulate` environment to dynamically plot the "equator" and "prime meridian" through a given point. The equations for the curves are entered explicitly, yet the artifacts still show up *when manipulate is running*. If I pause the slider, it eventually renders completely, and the artifact disappears. See a screen cap here: http://i.imgur.com/FsBxUVa.png

Comment: @Patch. Strange, no idea what this could be. Perhaps the work around is to plot multiple lines corresponding to each segment. For example a line from t=0 to t=2 Pi. And then add a new line in addition corresponding to the next loop (t=2 Pi to t = 4 Pi) etc etc?

Comment: @Dunlop That would work, but it would be a terrific inconvenience. Not only would I have to have Mathematica compute a different implicit solution every time, but the amount of time "t" between each loop will not always be $2\pi$. I'd also need to know the tangent vector the path left off with, and feed these in, each time I begin with new initial conditions.

Comment: @Patch. I guess it depends on whether your surface is periodic or not? If so then you could just calculate the path over large t, and then split it up into individual segments according to the boundaries of your bounding box. And then shift one of the coordinates so that you can plot these lines on your surface. As an aside could you edit your question so that you show your full code ? It is very difficult to try to reproduce what you are describing without this. Also it is not impossible that others, if they see the code, might have a solution.